# Unity bar Personal Folder Icon open a new icon on the unity bar when clicked

Tags: 11.10, unity, folder, filemanager

Since Ubuntu 11.10 the Personal folder Icon of unity bar act differently than 11.04.
In 11.04, when clicked, it opens a file manager window pointing to the personal folder and it is still associated with the icon (ie when I click again on the icon, it bring back the opened window at front).

In 11.10, it opens the file manager window pointing to the personal folder but associate it with a newly created file manager icon on the bar, so if I click again on the personal folder icon it opens a new window and does not bring back to front the already opened one.

Is there a way to restore previous behaviour ?

(I have this problem on two different computers)...

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I've resolved my problem. I've added some shortcuts to the rightclick, so the icon stayed the same as before. But some instructions have changed, so putting the changes below in the file ~/.local/share/applications/nautilus-home.desktop resolved my problem :

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Home Folder
GenericName=Home Folder
X-GNOME-FullName=Home Folder
Comment=Open your favourite folders in Nautilus
Exec=nautilus %U
Icon=user-home
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Core;
StartupNotify=true
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Bugzilla=GNOME
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Product=nautilus
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Component=general
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=nautilus

X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=Documents;Downloads;Pictures;Music;Videos;

[Documents Shortcut Group]
Name=Documents
Exec=nautilus Documents/
OnlyShowIn=Unity

[Downloads Shortcut Group]
Name=Téléchargements
Exec=nautilus Téléchargements/
OnlyShowIn=Unity

[Pictures Shortcut Group]
Name=Images
Exec=nautilus Images/
OnlyShowIn=Unity

[Music Shortcut Group]
Name=Musique
Exec=nautilus Musique/
OnlyShowIn=Unity

[Videos Shortcut Group]
Name=Vidéos
Exec=nautilus Vidéos/
OnlyShowIn=Unity
```

Them relaunching unity :

```
unity --replace
```